# Arrange css div elements for printing

Tags: html, css

I have a side showing 3 div elements arranged in a grid. The side is shown nicely on the screen. However, when trying to print the page, the elements overlap or are not shown at all. I use the following css:

```
@media print {
  #navigation { display: none; }
}

@page {
  margin: 0.05cm;
}

#maps {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
#map {
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#map_profiles {
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#map_hp {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#map_sp {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

The full example can be found at:
http://www.tikey.de/neuseeland/vergleich.html

The div maps contains all the others. Inside, map and map_profiles are next to each other and map_profiles contains map_hp and map_sp that are on top of each other. It looks alright on the screen but when printing, it's totally messed up. I've tried playing around with the css a lot but I didn't get it to work.

Comment: I noticed that the `@media print { } ` section is already closed in line 3 of what you posted. If that's the case in your real CSS file, this might be the reason for your troubles. (I write this with the assuption that this is your print style sheet?)

Comment: No, the @media print section is only used to hide the navigation part when printing.

Comment: aha. Well, maybe the `vh` height unit for the main element doesn't work that well, plus if you use "vertical-align" in the last two elements, you should also give them "display: inline-block"

Comment: I have also tried to  use width: 100% and height: 100% as well as width: 29cm and height: 20cm (and then printing on A4 landscape) but that hasn't worked either. Maybe I need a completely different size?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed one thing when I went to your link. My Browser zoom was at 120% and what you mentioned happened where the Images overlapped and was being messy but when I went to 100% zoom it worked fine. So maybe it's a resolution/zoom issue?

Try Using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and see if that would work.

Comment: Indeed, I can at least print the page if I choose a scale of 60% for printing. However, that also means that there is a lot of empty space on the page. Not sure why, though.